# R ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Consider the following code:

```
d <- data.frame(y = sample(LETTERS[1:8]), x = c(-1.6,-1.4,-1.2,0,0,1.2,1.3,1.4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(d, aes(y=x, x=y)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

Can anybody tell me how to force ggplot to NOT ORDER the data alphabetically? I used `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` so that my characters are not of type `factor`. Furthermore, why do I have to swap x and y from `aes(y=y, x=x)` to `aes(y=x, x=y)` that my y-data is plotted alongside the y-axis? Is that because of the `coord_flip()` option I use?

Comment: Note that ggplot2 converts to factor, if you pass it a character. And plotting order is determined by levels, which are then ordered alphabetically.

Comment: But that behaviour is standard for R factor creations - it is not *ggplot*'s doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```
ggplot(d, aes(y=x, x=factor(y, levels=y))) + ...
```

The reason the axis is alphabetical is that `geom_bar` turns the `x` variable into a `factor`. Default `levels` for a `factor` will go in alphabetical order, so you need to tell R to do otherwise.

The reason for `coord_flip` is that `geom_bar` treats the `x` variable as the bin and the `y` variable as the value.

Comment: thanks for this solution. however, what is still a bit weird is that the order is reversed. Let's say  y has values of ("A","C","H",...) than H is plotted on top followed by C and A rather than keeping the order of A on top followed by C and H. Do you see what I mean? Is it possible to reverse this order?

Comment: Yup - the reversal is due to `coord_flip` (starts on the bottom and goes up), so `rev` is a good fix.